# Mocking framework vs functional testing, why bother mocking?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, mocking

I understand with mocking frameworks we can override behavior of objects.  Which makes test easier and faster.  Simulating objects behaviors in a production environment can be good.  But then the question arises is mocking not simply for the developer ? at the end the functional test (which are real world test) show us what passed or failed. So why prolong the envitable ? Why bother mocking an object only to find out its not even working in production.  Why wait for the functional tester to find out that codes not working.  If we did not mock but instead used real test then we could find the bugs right away instead of pleasing ourselves with mocking.  This was an argument presented to me and it might be philosphical but what are your thoughts on mocking framework vs real world unit testing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good question. After a decade writing automated developer tests (and even creating a mocking library for my needs), I can only come to conclusion that unit tests which use mocking are *not* the best way to go.

Instead, writing acceptance-level integration tests has worked better for me. I only use mocking when there is no easy way around it.

I suspect there is still going to take several years before most developers share this view, though. Even today, creating (and running) "real-world" integration tests often is harder than just mocking dependencies away, due to the lack of good tooling support for such tests; too often, it's just easier to "cheat" and create a bunch of unit tests with mocking, rather than take the trouble of creating real tests that truly exercise the code in a more realistic way.